# Show only number and characters not Specific symbols

Tags: linux, grep

I want to show only the numbers and characters, not other specific symbols. I tried this:

```
grep [0-9,A-Z] ika
```

but working it is not working now, it shows specific symbols also.

Comment: the command you show will display lines with any of those characters in it; what's your desired output?  Also, be sure to quote that pattern to protect it from the shell, in case you had a file named `,` or `C` in your current directory, you wouldn't get what you expect.

Comment: Do you mean numbers and *letters*? "Symbols" are characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following examples show how to get what you want:

These commands show the whole line containing the search string.

```
$ <<< 'asdf$@12' grep as
asdf$@12
$ <<< 'asdf$@12' grep '[0-9A-Z]'
asdf$@12
```

You can high-light the search string in the line

```
$ <<< 'asdf$@12' grep --color '[0-9A-Z]'
asdf$@12
```

You can print only the search string (in this case one-character digits and upper case letters)

```
$ <<< 'asdf$@12' grep --color -o '[0-9A-Z]'
1
2
```

If you want all letters, you should search for lower case letters too

```
$ <<< 'asdf$@12' grep --color -o '[0-9A-Za-z]'
a
s
d
f
1
2
```

Comment: Do you want commas displayed in the result? If no, remove from the pattern resp. regex.

Comment: `touch C` for a quick reason why :)

Comment: Thanks for suggesting to remove the commas, @RudiC :-)

Answer (score 4):

Try also

```
<<< 'asdf$@12' tr -cd 'a-zA-Z0-9'
asdf12
```

or use a character class, like

```
tr -cd '[:alnum:]'
```